# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate, jpa-2.0, primefaces-5.2

Bom dia galera, estou com um problema estranho em minha aplicação somente depois que gero o War e envio para o Integrator, a aplicação não chega nem a abrir a tela de Login, é retornado esse erro:

> ```
> INFO: Exception when handling error trying to reset the response.
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
>     at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:3008)
>     at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2384)
>     at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:897)
>     at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.getSession(Unknown Source)
>     at javax.faces.context.ExternalContextWrapper.getSession(Unknown Source)
>     at br.com.mafra.filter.AuthorizationListener.afterPhase(AuthorizationListener.java:24)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleAfterPhase(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(Unknown Source)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at br.com.mafra.filter.ControleFilter.doFilter(ControleFilter.java:41)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
>     at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:190)
>     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> ```

Comment: A mensagem diz que é porque o servidor tenta escrever alguma coisa dentro do response depois de este já ter sido finalizado e enviado de volta ao navegador. Entretanto, sem o seu código não dá para saber qual é a causa desse erro.

Comment: Certo ... qual parte do codigo seria preciso ???

Comment: @rubStackOverflow Veja isso: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5359/132

Comment: Diego, olhando o stacktrace, eu acho que o problema está no `br.com.mafra.filter.AuthorizationListener.afterPhase`. Entretanto, o `br.com.mafra.filter.ControleFilter.doFilter` também seria uma outra possibilidade.